# Webpack 5: file-loader generates a copy of fonts with hash-name

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, fonts, webpack-5

I cant figure out whats going on here.
I use the file-loader to load the fonts of my application:

```
{
    test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        outputPath: 'assets/fonts/',
        publicPath: '../fonts/'
      }
    }]
  },
```

The fonts are also generated in the structure I specified: dist/assets/fonts.
`outputPath: 'assets/fonts/'` ... it seems to work correctly.

**But:** Webpack also packs the fonts with a hash as a name under /dist and sets the path in the CSS file to these files.

```
@font-face{font-family:"PaulGrotesk";font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(../../d9bc4e30281429c0cddd.eot);
```

[image: strange font files]

What is happening here? How can I prevent the additional files from being generated and used as a path?

**I am using**

- webpack: ^5.47.1
- webpack-cli: ^4.7.2

**My webpack.config:**

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  entry: './src/index.js',

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'assets/js/bundle_v1.0.0.js'
  },

  module: {

    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'index'),
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      },

      {
        test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'assets/fonts/',
            publicPath: '../fonts/'
          }
        }]
      },

      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            }
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },

    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
      /* https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/ */
    },
  },
  plugins: [

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'assets/css/bundle_v1.0.0.css'
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: 'body',
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
    })

  ]

};
```

Comment: Hey @toge - I had the same issue and have posted my answer below, hopefully is of some help!

Answer (score 56):

I had the exact same issue as the OP (@toge) having migrated from Webpack 4 to 5. Whilst I was looking to implement the solution posted by @seanbun, I came across the following setup for the new Webpack 5 asset modules config that allowed me to get both my previous `file-loader` svgs and font files to generate correctly without duplication in the root output folder:

```js
{
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)$/,
    type: 'asset/resource',
    generator: {
        filename: './fonts/[name][ext]',
    },
},
```

This tells webpack to handle it via the asset modules config but output to a custom filepath, similar to how the `file-loader` config used to work.

This setup also removed my need to downgrade `css-loader` too which was an added benefit

Comment: Yes, that works for me!

Comment: this is the winner, thanks

Comment: This solved my issues when going from webpack 4 to webpack5

Comment: Wow! What a keen eye you have. I swear I have read through all the webpack documentation several times by now. Thank you for spotting this
https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-fonts
Unsure where you found the generator part? It wasn't very clear
Maybe https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rulegeneratorfilename

Comment: @harry-fin
 You're amazing. Thank you so much! After hours of soul-searching and gut-wrenching later, THIS WORKED FOR ME TOO!!!

Comment: Yes, that works for me as well. thank you so much.

Comment: I had the same issue and resolved it with this answer.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, Webpack 5 has a `Asset Modules` function which allows one to use asset files (fonts, icons, etc) without configuring additional loaders i.e. `file-loader`, `url-loader` and etc. The `Asset Modules` provides four types to handle different type of asset. You can find more details at https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/.

So, when you add below rule for font files, the files are acutally handled by the `Asset Modules` as well as the `file-loader`.

```
    {
        test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'assets/fonts/',
            publicPath: '../fonts/'
          }
        }]
    }
```

In this case, we want to use our own `file-loader` and disable the `Asset Module`. We can set the type to 'javascript/auto'. This would follow your path setting and keep the font files in the `assets/fonts` folder.

```
    {
        test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        **type: "javascript/auto",**
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'assets/fonts/',
            publicPath: '../fonts/'
          }
        }]
    }
```

P.S I was using `css-loader 6.2.0` and had an error - `url.replace is not a function`. I downgraded to `css-loader 5.2.7` to resolve the issue.

Comment: in my case, svg files are also copied to fonts folder for some reason, i don't want them in my dist, only the fonts. is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem for a while and for my case here is how I solved it by just adding two lines of code. **type: "javascript/auto"** and **esModule: false**

```
{
test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
exclude: [IMG_DIR, /node_modules/],
type: "javascript/auto",
use: {
  loader: "file-loader",
  options: {
    name: "[name].[ext]",
    publicPath: "../assets/fonts/",
    esModule: false,
  }
```

I hope this solves it :)

Answer (score 0):

Loaders are applied from last to first. So my guess is that placing the file loader below the css/sass loaders could fix the issue.

The fonts may not be registered this way when needed by the css loader and therefore loaded twice.

Comment: No, that does not work unfortunately. I found out that it works with webpack 4. Maybe that's the approach.

Answer (score 0):

I already had my font files in a serveable location so I didn't need to copy the assets.  (I'm confused why webpack did this by default).  My solution was to ignore those files by:

```
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
      resourceRegExp: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)$/
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem but in my case problem was solved by "type:'asset/inline'"

```
   {
      test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot)$/,
      type:'asset/inline',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {          
        esModule: false,
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        outputPath: '../assets/fonts/',
        publicPath: '../assets/fonts/'
      }
    },
```