# Webpack image loading doesn't load anything

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have problem with loading images using webpack, I have ThreeJS project and I wanted to add some images to it, but it doesnt work, it shows as *hash*.png in the sources tab, but with error, also on the website its just like I've never imported it, my webpack config:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCSSExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/script.js"),
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.[contenthash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: path.resolve(__dirname, "../static") }],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/index.html"),
      minify: true,
    }),
    new MiniCSSExtractPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // HTML
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: ["html-loader"],
      },

      // JS
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },

      // CSS
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCSSExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },

      // Images
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]",
            options: {
              outputPath: "assets/images/",
            },
          },
        ],
      },

      // Fonts
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              outputPath: "assets/fonts/",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I tried some answers from internert but none of them worked.

[image: Import]

[image]

Comment: Which version of webpack are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack 5. You should replace file-loader, raw-loader and url-loader with [webpack 5 asset modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/). Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68634225/webpack-5-file-loader-generates-a-copy-of-fonts-with-hash-name) post.